# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, unable to iterate through object array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am a beginner in react please help me with this problem
when I am iterating through the array of objects that I have imported from category.json using map function, I am passing the props of object to my Category component, so when my category page is rendering it gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.`

App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import category from './data/categories.json';
import Categ from './Components/Categ';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(category);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(item => (
        <Categ key={item.id} name={item.name} desc={item.description} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`

Categ.js

```js
import React from 'react';

function Categ({ props }) {
  console.log(props);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <p>{props.desc}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Categ;
```

category.json

```js
[
  {
    "id": "fgsa2142fa",
    "name": "Keyboards",
    "description": "Buy different keyboard from any brand available"
  },
  {
    "id": "xasgy42fa",
    "name": "Headphones",
    "description": "Find best-fit for your ears"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

When your component first renders, your `data` object is undefined. You can solve this quite easily by a number of ways:

1. Optional chaining: ?. notation will call `map` function only if data is not falsy

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(category);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data?.map(item => (
        <Categ key={item.id} name={item.name} desc={item.description} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. Conditional rendering:

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(category);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data && data.map(item => (
        <Categ key={item.id} name={item.name} desc={item.description} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

or:

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(category);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data ? data.map(item => (
        <Categ key={item.id} name={item.name} desc={item.description} />
      )) : <p> No data </p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Essentially, `data && data.map` and `data?.map` does the same thing here.

3. @Patryk's suggestion:

```
(data || []).map
```

Comment: `(data || []).map`

Answer (score 0):

> **Why undefined ?**
>
> You are passing the props as destruct format in Category. it does't  have `name` key

You could pass the `props` as single param instead destruct

Do like this in `category`

```
function Categ(props) {
```

And also better validate the `data` before itreate

```
data && data.map
```

Answer (score 0):

The  data variable renders as undefined for the first time, one way you can manage this as well is like the following:

```
 function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(category);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!data ? <h1>Loading</h1> : data.map(item => (
        <Categ key={item.id} name={item.name} desc={item.description} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```